# Bilateral filter algorithm

Tags: javascript, graphics, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement a simple bilateral filter in javascript. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
// For each pixel
for (var y = kernelSize; y < height-kernelSize; y++) {
    for (var x = kernelSize; x < width-kernelSize; x++) {
        var pixel = (y*width + x)*4;
        var sumWeight = 0;
        outputData[pixel] = 0;
        outputData[pixel+1] = 0;
        outputData[pixel+2] = 0;
        outputData[pixel+3] = inputData[pixel+3];

        // For each neighbouring pixel
        for(var i=-kernelSize; i<=kernelSize; i++) {
            for(var j=-kernelSize; j<=kernelSize; j++) {
                var kernel = ((y+i)*width+x+j)*4;
                var dist = Math.sqrt(i*i+j*j);
                var colourDist = Math.sqrt((inputData[kernel]-inputData[pixel])*(inputData[kernel]-inputData[pixel])+
                        (inputData[kernel+1]-inputData[pixel+1])*(inputData[kernel+1]-inputData[pixel+1])+
                        (inputData[kernel+2]-inputData[pixel+2])*(inputData[kernel+2]-inputData[pixel+2]));
                var curWeight = 1/(Math.exp(dist*dist/72)*Math.exp(colourDist*colourDist*8));
                sumWeight += curWeight;
                outputData[pixel] += curWeight*inputData[pixel];
                outputData[pixel+1] += curWeight*inputData[pixel+1];
                outputData[pixel+2] += curWeight*inputData[pixel+2];
            }
        }

        outputData[pixel] /= sumWeight;
        outputData[pixel+1] /= sumWeight;
        outputData[pixel+2] /= sumWeight;
    }
}
```

inputData is from a html5 canvas object and is in the form of rgba.
My images are either coming up with no changes or with patches of black around edges depending on how i change this formula:

```
var curWeight = 1/(Math.exp(dist*dist/72)*Math.exp(colourDist*colourDist*8));
```

Unfortunately I'm still new to html/javascript and image vision algorithms and my search have come up with no answers. My guess is there is something wrong with the way curWeight is calculated. What am I doing wrong here? Should I have converted the input image to CIElab/hsv first?

Comment: Here is a heavily documented bilateral filter matlab code that I wrote, and it works on rgba images (including the edges). http://pastebin.com/pLu4v1dC This is just fore reference, Will look at your code in a moment

Comment: Hello, I am facing a similar issue with a bilateral filter. Could you please help answer the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59004858/noise-in-the-output-pixels-while-implementing-a-filter-what-could-be-the-reason Also, why do you take `Math.sqrt(i*i+j*j);` as the euclidean distance? Should not it be a proper distance formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error in the code. The problem was I was adding each pixel to itself instead of its surrounding neighbours. I'll leave the corrected code here in case anyone needs a bilateral filter algorithm.

```
outputData[pixel] += curWeight*inputData[kernel];
outputData[pixel+1] += curWeight*inputData[kernel+1];
outputData[pixel+2] += curWeight*inputData[kernel+2];
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm no Javasript expert: Are the RGB values 0..255? If so, `Math.exp(colourDist*colourDist*8)` will yield extremely large values - you'll probably want to scale colourDist to the range [0..1].

BTW: Why do you calculate the `sqrt` of `dist` and `colourDist` if you only need the squared distance afterwards?

Comment: Hah now i feel stupid... I've edited the code to normalise the colour dist to [0,1] and removed the sqrt functions

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your images turn out black/weird in the edges because you don't filter the edges. A short look at your code would show that you begin at (kernelSize,kernelSize) and finish at (width-kernelSize,height-kernelSize) - this means that you only filter a smaller rectangle inside the image where your have a margin of kernelSize on each side which is unfilterred. Without knowing your javscript/html5, I would assume that your outputData array is initialized with zero's (which means black) and then not touching them would leave them black. See my link the comment to your post for code that does handle the edges.

Other than that, follow @nikie's answer - your probably want to make sure the color distance is clamped to the range of [0,1] - youo can do this by adding the line `colourDist = colourDist / (MAX_COMP * Math,sqrt(3))` (directly after the first line to calculate it). where `MAX_COMP` is the maximal value a color component in the image can have (usually 255)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding matlab code. Whats the domain of the input values for the colour exp functions?

Comment: @Skul: My code works on grey images (so there is exactly one color component). I have uploaded a new code for RGB images here: http://pastebin.com/UsBBBkeK
Basically, exp receives a 2d matrix of values (the differences in our case) and computes the exponent of each value. It then returns the resulting matrix. So result(i,j) = e ^ src(i,j)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I understand the algo better now =)